# CodenameOne APK is not zip aligned

Tags: android, zip, alignment, apk, codenameone

Today my build for Android is still ok using CodenameOne but it is failed to upload to Google Play store with message below. This was not happened for last builds. Any idea?

**You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was an issue coming from the latest gradle update, it is already fixed on the build servers and should work fine by now